# Blender GLSL Export to THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, blender

I'm looking to use [this plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/Export_GLSL#Using) for blender to generate GLSL code for import into three.js.

I'm not that familiar with GLSL and  don't really know where to begin as to what variables need to be renamed to get this to work.

Here is example of the [fragment and vertex shaders](http://shdr.bkcore.com/#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)

As you can see from the demo I'm already getting lots of errors...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some more info to help narrow down what the problem is rather than "please fix this code". I.e. what is the shader for, which parts don't compile, what don't you understand about the error messages? Also please include the key parts of the code in the post.

Comment: It's actually just a pure flat shaded red color that I exported using glsl exporter in blender.  What I was trying to do was identify the areas in the code I need to tweak in order to convert from openGL to webGL with the intention of being able to  create more complex shaders in blender and convert to webGL --  The obvious thing I noticed was that there is a gl_ prefix on the vertex shader... not sure if I have to remove this...  There's also an else if statement that screwing thing up as well... remove this?  Also, what are the uniforms?

Comment: These are the all the kinds of things that need to be in the question :), and more about webgl feature workarounds than blender or threejs

Comment: the error is pretty straightforward and is printed in the footer: _cannot convert from 'highp 4-component vector of float' to 'float'_

Comment: instead of writing shaders in blender, why dont you get familiar with how they work in webgl (what's available in the spec) and three.js (what stuff three injects)

Comment: Have been reading up on it... Unfortunately not that much in the way of just starting out resources.

Comment: Hi Master Splinter, have you had a look to my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

as long as I can see at a first sight, you are facing using _gl_ClipVertex_ which is not implemented in WebGL as it is not present in OpenGL ES.

source:
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/common/notes/APITables.xml